# How to keep inter dependent knockout.js observable in sync

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 3 knockout observables which are inter related with each other. They are

retail_price, selling_price, discount

When the user changes one value, the other other observables are updated. 
For example,

- If the user enter selling price to 1000, the retail price gets set as 1000 and discount as 0.
- Following the above example, now if the user goes and edits retail_price as 2000, the discount gets updated to 50.

Now all this work fine if I do not have afterkeydown event. So when the user enters any value and moves to the next box, it is ok.

The problem is that when I keep afterkeydown, as soon as i start to type, based on the first character, the other values are calculated. Now when I enter the second integer, the values are messed up.

For example,

selling_price = 10, retail_price = 1, discount = -900

I am not able to figure out a solution for this. Any suggestions?

Regards,

**Update**

Sorry for not being clear. The user can update any of the three fields. I have created a fiddle for this. Currently, I do not have control on the order of fields being filled with values. They can be filled in any order.

- Start with retail: Selling gets set as retail and discount = 0
- Start with selling: Retails gets set as selling and discount = 0
- Start with discount. Can add either retail or selling next.

The user can enter values in any order.

http://jsfiddle.net/EcD3d/5/

Html:

```
<code>

<div>retail_price:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: retail_price.formatted, hasfocus: retail_price.isFocused, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
<div>selling_price:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: selling_price.formatted, hasfocus: selling_price.isFocused, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
<div>discount:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: discount, hasfocus: discount.isFocused, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</div>

</code>
```

Javascript:

```
function hasOwnProperty(obj, prop) {
    var proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
    return (prop in obj) && (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);
}

function roundNumber(value, precision, flt) {
    var precision = precision || 0,
        neg = value < 0,
        power = Math.pow(10, precision),
        value = Math.round(value * power),
        integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power)),
        fraction = String((neg ? -value : value) % power),
        padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');

    if (flt === true) {
        integral = parseFloat(integral);
    }
    return precision ? integral + '.' + padding + fraction : integral;
}

var util = {};
util.format = function (value, prefix) {
    var pr = prefix || '';
    toks = roundNumber(value, 2).replace('-', '').split('.');
    var display = pr + $.map(toks[0].split('').reverse(), function (elm, i) {
        return [(i % 3 === 0 && i > 0 ? ',' : ''), elm];
    }).reverse().join('') + '.' + toks[1];

    return value < 0 ? '-' + display : display;
};
ko.subscribable.fn.formatted = function (options) {
    var target = this;
    var _options = (options === undefined) ? {} : options;
    var _prefix = hasOwnProperty(_options, 'prefix') ? _options.prefix : '';
    var _precision = hasOwnProperty(_options, 'precision') ? _options.precision : 2;
    var _type = hasOwnProperty(_options, 'type') ? _options.type : 2;

    var format = function (value) {
        switch (_type) {
            case 1:
                return util.format(roundNumber(value, _precision), _prefix); //currency w/ symbol
            case 2:
                return roundNumber(value, _precision); //reg float
            default:
                throw new Error('illegal type');
        }
    };

    var focused = ko.observable(false);

    var writeTarget = function (value) {
        var stripped = value;
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            stripped = String(value).replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');
        }

        //target(parseFloat(stripped));
        value = parseFloat(stripped);
        focused() ? target(!isFinite(value) ? 0 : value) : target(!isFinite(value) ? 0 : roundNumber(value, _precision)); // Write to underlying storage
    };

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return target();
        },
        write: writeTarget
    });

    result.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (focused()) {
                return (isNaN(target()) ? '' : target()); // Write to underlying storage
            }
            return format(target());
        },
        write: writeTarget
    });

    result.isNegative = ko.computed(function () {
        return target() < 0;
    });

    result.isFocused = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return focused();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            focused(value);
        }
    });


    return result;
};



var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.retail_price = ko.observable(0).extend({
        throttle: 100
    }).formatted({
        type: 1
    });
    self.selling_price = ko.observable(0).extend({
        throttle: 100
    }).formatted({
        type: 1
    });
    self.discount = ko.observable(0);


    // Whenever the retail price changes, change the selling price for jewelry
    self.retail_price.subscribe(function () {
        if (parseFloat(self.selling_price()) !== 0) {
            self.updateDiscount();
            return;
        }

        if (self.retail_price.isFocused()) {
            self.changeSellingPrice();
        }

    });

    // Whenever the discount changes, change the selling price
    self.discount.subscribe(function () {
        self.changeSellingPrice();
    });

    self.selling_price.subscribe(function (v) {
        if (self.selling_price.isFocused()) {
            if (parseFloat(self.retail_price()) !== 0) {
                self.updateDiscount();
                return;
            }

            var retPrice = (v * 100) / (100 - self.discount());
            self.retail_price(isNaN(retPrice) ? 0 : roundNumber(retPrice, 2));

        }
    });

    self.updateDiscount = function () {

        var retPr = parseFloat(self.retail_price());
        var askPr = parseFloat(self.selling_price());
        var discount = 100 * (retPr - askPr) / retPr;
        self.discount(!isFinite(discount) ? 0 : roundNumber(discount, 2));

    };

    self.changeSellingPrice = function () {
        var sellingPrice = self.retail_price() - (self.retail_price() * self.discount()) / 100;
        self.selling_price(isNaN(sellingPrice) ? 0 : roundNumber(sellingPrice, 2));
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Why do you want to have the `afterkeydown` setting if you don't your values updated after each key?

Comment: If you are insist of the `afterkeydown` you can probably you the [throttle extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) to delay the calculation: http://jsfiddle.net/Y436L/

Comment: I tried the throttle extender but it does not entirely work as in the above case, If I stop after 1 and then enter 0, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could make discount a computed observable and include some sanity checks:

```
var discount = ko.computed(function() {
  var discount;

  // your calculation goes here
  // discount = retail_price() - selling_price() …

  return discount > 0 ? discount : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added another observable to track if the user has entered a particular value. For eg. a observable if the user has entered retail value.

Not sure if this is the right way or not but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Well the value is not updating because you have a check that the value should be greater than 0 (zero) then only it will update the value. Now as you are using afterkeydown binding so after pressing one digit it updates the value to that as initially it was 0(zero) and thereafter it stopped working as the value is non zero.

I assume in such case you should remove valueupdate binding and also remove the check for isfocused. I have made some changes. Please go through this and let me know if you still need any concerns:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLKEb/

Html:

```
<div>retail_price:
<input type="text" data-bind="value: retail_price.formatted, hasfocus: retail_price.isFocused" />
</div>
<div>selling_price:
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selling_price.formatted, hasfocus: selling_price.isFocused" />
</div>
<div>discount:
<input type="text" data-bind="value: discount, hasfocus: discount.isFocused" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function hasOwnProperty(obj, prop) {
var proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
return (prop in obj) && (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);
}

function roundNumber(value, precision, flt) {
var precision = precision || 0,
    neg = value < 0,
    power = Math.pow(10, precision),
    value = Math.round(value * power),
    integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power)),
    fraction = String((neg ? -value : value) % power),
    padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');

if (flt === true) {
    integral = parseFloat(integral);
}
return precision ? integral + '.' + padding + fraction : integral;
}

var util = {};
util.format = function (value, prefix) {
var pr = prefix || '';
toks = roundNumber(value, 2).replace('-', '').split('.');
var display = pr + $.map(toks[0].split('').reverse(), function (elm, i) {
    return [(i % 3 === 0 && i > 0 ? ',' : ''), elm];
}).reverse().join('') + '.' + toks[1];

return value < 0 ? '-' + display : display;
};
ko.subscribable.fn.formatted = function (options) {
var target = this;
var _options = (options === undefined) ? {} : options;
var _prefix = hasOwnProperty(_options, 'prefix') ? _options.prefix : '';
var _precision = hasOwnProperty(_options, 'precision') ? _options.precision : 2;
var _type = hasOwnProperty(_options, 'type') ? _options.type : 2;

var format = function (value) {
    switch (_type) {
        case 1:
            return util.format(roundNumber(value, _precision), _prefix); //currency w/ symbol
        case 2:
            return roundNumber(value, _precision); //reg float
        default:
            throw new Error('illegal type');
    }
};

var focused = ko.observable(false);

var writeTarget = function (value) {
    var stripped = value;
    if (isNaN(value)) {
        stripped = String(value).replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');
    }

    //target(parseFloat(stripped));
    value = parseFloat(stripped);
    focused() ? target(!isFinite(value) ? 0 : value) : target(!isFinite(value) ? 0 : roundNumber(value, _precision)); // Write to underlying storage
};

var result = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return target();
    },
    write: writeTarget
});

result.formatted = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        if (focused()) {
            return (isNaN(target()) ? '' : target()); // Write to underlying storage
        }
        return format(target());
    },
    write: writeTarget
});

result.isNegative = ko.computed(function () {
    return target() < 0;
});

result.isFocused = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return focused();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        focused(value);
    }
});


return result;
};



var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

self.retail_price = ko.observable(0).extend({
    throttle: 100
}).formatted({
    type: 1
});
self.selling_price = ko.observable(0).extend({
    throttle: 100
}).formatted({
    type: 1
});
self.discount = ko.observable(0);


// Whenever the retail price changes, change the selling price for jewelry
self.retail_price.subscribe(function () {
    if (parseFloat(self.selling_price()) !== 0) {
        self.updateDiscount();
        return;
    }

    if (self.retail_price.isFocused()) {
        self.changeSellingPrice();
    }

});

// Whenever the discount changes, change the selling price
self.discount.subscribe(function () {
    self.changeSellingPrice();
});

self.selling_price.subscribe(function (v) {
        var retPrice = (v * 100) / (100 - self.discount());
        self.retail_price(isNaN(retPrice) ? 0 : roundNumber(retPrice, 2));
        if (parseFloat(self.retail_price()) !== 0) {
            self.updateDiscount();
        }
});

self.updateDiscount = function () {

    var retPr = parseFloat(self.retail_price());
    var askPr = parseFloat(self.selling_price());
    var discount = 100 * (retPr - askPr) / retPr;
    self.discount(!isFinite(discount) ? 0 : roundNumber(discount, 2));

};

self.changeSellingPrice = function () {
    var sellingPrice = self.retail_price() - (self.retail_price() * self.discount()) / 100;
    self.selling_price(isNaN(sellingPrice) ? 0 : roundNumber(sellingPrice, 2));
};

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```